# Convert Visual Studio solution file from 2008 to 2010 using msbuild

Tags: visual-studio

I have a solution file for a solution build in Visual Studio 2008. I want to convert this solution to a Visual Studio 2010 file using only the command line. I know I can open the solution in Visual Studio and it will convert it for me. How can I perform essentially the same conversion using the command line and without user intervention? I'd prefer to use msbuild, but any tool suitable for this purpose should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w15a82ay(v=VS.100).aspx