# Convert Visual Studio 2008 solution to 2010 WITHOUT Visual Studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010

[This question looked promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320206/convert-visual-studio-solution-file-from-2008-to-2010-using-msbuild) but the accepted answer requires using devenv, which is part of Visual Studio.

Say I have a build system that I don't want to waste a Visual Studio license on, but I want to have it automatically convert 2008 solution files to 2010 and build them using msbuild from Windows SDK 7.1. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried using [Visual C++ 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express)?

Comment: If you mean TFS/Team Build, then you are permitted to install VS without license violation. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350 (page 19 at the bottom).

Comment: Also, do you have an MSDN subscription with your Visual Studio 2008 license?

Comment: @StingyJack: It's just a Windows machine that is going to be running a buildbot slave.

Comment: There was a very drastic change in the C++ project file format from .vcproj to vcxproj.  Finding non-VS tooling is going to be very difficult.  Making the conversion just once on a dev machine is an obvious approach.

Answer (score -1):

Someone wrote a tool for that.
I suggest trying it on some dummy project, before converting the real one.

http://stevedunns.blogspot.co.il/2010/02/tool-to-switch-project-files-between.html

Comment: It looked promising, but it is a C++ project and his tool doesn't work on those.